# Reload toggle buttons Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an interactive skill tree for our employees, so they can record their progress and in turn determine where to take their careers. I've created a userform with toggle buttons that then record the true/false so that they can monitor their progress.

The problem I have is that when I close the form, the entries are stored but upon re-opening the userform is reset. The toggle buttons are all back to their default position. I would like to be able to reopen the file and have the userform reflect the data that was last stored, so some toggle buttons should be pressed.

So far, I've managed to get the userform to open up automatically, but I do not know how to have the form reflect the previous state, if this is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you `Hide` the form instead of unloading it the values will be retained at the time of the next `Show`. However all entries will be lost when the application is shut down. The only way to preserve them is to store them somewhere in the workbook, perhaps in an invisible sheet, and reload them with the `Initialise` even procedure.

Comment: Thanks, The initialise procedure did the trick

Comment: Since my suggestion solved your problem I have re-posted it as an answer so as to let forum statistics how that your question didn't go unattended. Please nark it as "accepted"  to close the thread. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Hide the form instead of unloading it the values will be retained at the time of the next Show. However all entries will be lost when the application is shut down. The only way to preserve them is to store them somewhere in the workbook, perhaps in an invisible sheet, and reload them with the Initialise even procedure.